# Extension method for a class declared in an external module throws 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to extend fluent-ffmpeg to to have runAsync() method, but receiving a compile-time error whenever I have my extension imported.

`import '../infrastructure/ffmpeg-extensions');`

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

```
   8 | }
   9 |
> 10 | FfmpegCommand.prototype.runAsync = function (this: FfmpegCommand): Promise<void> {
     |               ^
  11 |   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  12 |     this.on('end', () => resolve(null)).on('error', (err) => reject(err));
  13 |   });

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/adapters/infrastructure/ffmpeg-extensions.ts:10:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/adapters/media-editing/trim-video.spec.ts:1:1)
```

Here's the code of ffmpeg-extensions.ts:

```
import { FfmpegCommand } from 'fluent-ffmpeg';

declare module 'fluent-ffmpeg' {
  interface FfmpegCommand {
    runAsync(): Promise<void>;
  }
}

FfmpegCommand.prototype.runAsync = function (this: FfmpegCommand): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.on('end', () => resolve(null)).on('error', (err) => reject(err));
  });
};
```

Searched everything I could over the internet but was unable to solve it. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably found the answer to this by now but just in case and for the benefit of anyone coming across this question; this is the solution that works for me.

I extend fluent-ffmpeg so that it has a graceful shutdown method which closes the stream and writes the end of stream data to the file. This is instead of using the fluent-ffmpeg kill command which seems to corrupt the output file.

The code below has worked for a while but following recent dependency updates I encountered this problem and came across this question.

It appears that the problem is in the way that that fluent-ffmepg is imported. Originally, I used the following line of code to import the library.

```
import FfmpegCommand = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
```

and then implementation follows

```
FfmpegCommand.prototype.shutdown = function () {
  if (!this.ffmpegProc) {
    console.log('No running ffmpeg process, cannot send signal');
  } else {
    this.ffmpegProc.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
    this.ffmpegProc.stdin.write('q\n');
  }
  return this;
};
```

Updates to the project dependencies resulted in the error above but only in the unit test code, the production code seemed fine. Changing the import statement to the following fixed the unit tests and also worked in the production code.

```
import * as FfmpegCommand from 'fluent-ffmpeg';
```

The above works but it doesn't seem right; hovering over the import in VSCode shows the following:
[image: FfMepgCommand type aliases]

The name is now an alias for both the function and the namespace? Interestingly though the JavaScript generated from import statement is:

```
const FfmpegCommand = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
```

Which is probably what you would have written in JavaScript directly.

For context the solution is using Node 16.x, TypeScript v4.8.4, ts-node v10.9.1 and @tsconfig/node16 v1.03.

The graceful shutdown method code comes from another answer on this site 2 years ago (IIRC). I looked for it again so that I could add a reference to it but couldn't find it. Apologies if it's your code please feel free to add a reference to this answer.